# Can VPN steal passwords from client?

Tags: security, vpn, passwords

If I subscribe to a vpn service, then use it and log in to paypal, type my password there and everything... can they see it?

if i'm not mistaken the password is sent to the vpn server, and the vpn server sends it to paypal right?  so nothing stops them from seeing it?

Comment: Your paypal password is actually never sent to the VPN server but rather it is a hash of your password that is sent. However, it is not entire immune to man-in-the-middle attacks, see the answer below.

Comment: https connection is secure.  The only way a VPN service could intercept it is if you were connecting to a secure website through a MiTM attack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Paypal and most other sites with logins utilize a secured connection of their own and, when properly configured, will encrypt all communication between your browser and their server on their own.

VPNs are protected tunnels connecting computers. If a computer in the VPN connects to a secured site, the security of the site will run IN ADDITION TO the protection of the tunnel.

If you are connecting to an unsecured site or an improperly secured site, the VPN administrators may be able to see the data passed between your computer and the target server.

Comment: However, if you install software from the VPN provider on your computer, that may enable them to set up their own certificate as a trusted signing authority and use it to spoof SSL domains. If you want to be entirely safe, only use a VPN that you can connect to with your OS's standard VPN client -- don't install any of their software.

Comment: That is a very good point.